# How can I remove leading and trailing non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to "trim" non-alphanumerics from a string, similar to how `trim()` works with whitespace.

Help me convert `#str|ng#` to `str|ng`.

I can remove trailing non-alphanumerics with:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\W+$/', '', $string); // converts `#str|ng#` to `#str|ng`
```

And leading with:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^\W+/', '', $string); // converts `#str|ng#` to `str|ng#`
```

But how can I accomplish both at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a `^\W+|\W+$` pattern like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^\W+|\W+$/', '', $string);
```

This will replace any non-alphanumeric characters (note this doesn't include underscores) which appear either at the beginning or end of the string. The `|` is an alternation, which will match any string which matches either the pattern on the left or the pattern on the right. The `^` matches the beginning of the chain.

If you also need to remove underscores, use a character class like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex, use `trim()` and specify what to trim (it trims whitespace by default):

```
$string = trim($string, "#");
```

Docs: http://php.net/trim

Comment: Ha! Touché. Unfortunately my real case isn't so clean.

Comment: Ah well, regex it is then!